# Access an Ubuntu (WSL) folder from Windows

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Ubuntu on Windows 10. I've created a user id and there I created some folders. Now I want to copy those folders to my Windows folder in, say, `E:` drive. How can I get access to the folder that I created in Ubuntu in the Windows interface? I made that folder in `/home/user/directory`.

Comment: Copy from Ubuntu command line. Accessing the WSL files from Windows is not supported.

Comment: @muru IMHO, this is not a duplicate. The asker of this question wants the opposite. To access a Windows disk from Ubuntu is a part of the solution but it does not solve it fully while [Joe Ford’s answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/987955/250300) does.

Comment: That's why my comment says the "opposite" is not supported.

Answer (score 6):

All Windows' disks are available through `/mnt/`, so you can copy it to `E:` using Bash:

```
cp -r /home/user/direcory /mnt/e
```

Root of Ubuntu is located at `%LOCALAPPDATA%\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs`.